# Testing a HLS playlist

Tags: testing, streaming, http-live-streaming

I have generated a HLS adaptive streaming playlist with 3 different quality of videos using AWS elastic transcoder, which is configured to stream over cloudfront.

How do I test if this playlist is properly adapting based on the internet speed and other parameters?

regards
Abhishek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have access to Apple's HTTP Live Streaming tools, you can [validate your HLS video streams](http://hlsbook.net/validating-hls-video-streams/) by using the `mediastreamvalidator` tool.

Alternatively, you could try using a web proxy that allows bandwidth throttling, such as [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/proxying/throttling/) or [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler). Try altering the bandwidth setting then check if the player fetches a different playlist that corresponds to the (simulated) bandwidth available.

Comment: what HLS tool would you use to test the HLS stream?